# Swift Macros: ReturnClauseSyntax

Tags: swift, macros, swift-macro

I am doing some testing and figuring out with the new **Swift Macros** but I came across a hurdle I can't seem to figure out, also because there isn't a lot of helpful guides on them yet.

So first of all, if the appliance of the macro is a good idea at all, we leave that aside for now.

What I am trying to achieve is to create an `@attached(member)` macro which automatically adds an Service to a `struct` with all the basic **REST** operations such as `get(id: String)`, `patch()`, `getAll()`, `delete(id: String)` etcetera.

So I came quite far with the implementation but I can't seem to figure out how to create the `ReturnClauseSyntax` which should just return an instance of the type on which the macro is added. See code example below:

```
public struct ServiceMacro: MemberMacro {
    public static func expansion(
        of node: SwiftSyntax.AttributeSyntax,
        providingMembersOf declaration: some SwiftSyntax.DeclGroupSyntax,
        in context: some SwiftSyntaxMacros.MacroExpansionContext
    ) throws -> [SwiftSyntax.DeclSyntax] {
        guard let structDecl = declaration.as(StructDeclSyntax.self) else {
            // TODO: Emit an error
            return []
        }
        
        let initializer = try EnumDeclSyntax("enum Service") {
            FunctionDeclSyntax(
                funcKeyword: "static func",
                name: "get",
                signature: FunctionSignatureSyntax(
                    parameterClause: FunctionParameterClauseSyntax(
                        parameters: FunctionParameterListSyntax(
                            arrayLiteral: FunctionParameterSyntax(
                                stringLiteral: "id: String"
                            )
                        )
                    ),
                    trailingTrivia: .init(stringLiteral: " -> \(structDecl.name.trimmed)")
                ),
                bodyBuilder: {
                    "return \(structDecl.name.trimmed)()"
                }
            )
        }

        return [DeclSyntax(initializer)]
    }
}
```

So this results in the following expansion:

```
@Service
struct Recipe {
    enum Service {
       static func get(id: String) -> Recipe {
           return Recipe()
       }
    }
}
```

But as you can see in the macro implementation code I am setting the trailing trivia by using a `stringLiteral` which doesn't feel right and probably isn't right.

Now I am wondering how I can achieve the same by using the `returnClause` parameter which expects a `ReturnClauseSyntax`. I just for now want it to return an instance of the struct it is applied to.

Maybe it's really easy and I couldn't find it correctly in the docs, but also this whole syntax is new to me so would be really helpful if someone could point me in the right direction.

*Also other suggestions on the implementation are more than welcome as this is new to me and a lot of people probably.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

indeed it's not that hard.

You can retrieve the type name of the struct you are working on like that

```
guard let name = declaration.as(StructDeclSyntax.self)?.name.text
else {return []}
```

Then you can convert it to a TypeSyntax and pass this to the type parameter of `ReturnClauseSyntax` initialiser like so :

```
ReturnClauseSyntax(type: TypeSyntax(stringLiteral: name)
```

Now you can combine all that together :

```
public struct ServiceMacro: MemberMacro {
    public static func expansion(
        of node: SwiftSyntax.AttributeSyntax,
        providingMembersOf declaration: some SwiftSyntax.DeclGroupSyntax,
        in context: some SwiftSyntaxMacros.MacroExpansionContext
    ) throws -> [SwiftSyntax.DeclSyntax] {
        guard let structDecl = declaration.as(StructDeclSyntax.self) else {
            // TODO: Emit an error
            return []
        }
        let name = structDecl.name.text
        let initializer = try EnumDeclSyntax("enum Service") {
            FunctionDeclSyntax(
                funcKeyword: "static func",
                name: "get",
                signature: FunctionSignatureSyntax(
                    parameterClause: FunctionParameterClauseSyntax(
                        parameters: FunctionParameterListSyntax(
                            arrayLiteral: FunctionParameterSyntax(
                                stringLiteral: "id: String"
                            )
                        )
                    ),
                    returnClause: ReturnClauseSyntax(type: TypeSyntax(stringLiteral: name)
                ),
                bodyBuilder: {
                    "return \(structDecl.name.trimmed)()"
                }
            )
        }

        return [DeclSyntax(initializer)]
    }
}
```